How to enumerate theories logically equivalent to natural deduction?
Natural deduction seems to generally be structured around the idea of (an/) introduction and elimination rules(s) for each logical symbol.
I heard that that was an attempt to capture the way humans reason, but I don’t find all the rules seem like they are simple ways one observes humans thinking by.
For example, $A \wedge B \vdash A, B$ makes sense to me. It seems elemental, although I don’t know if it is the most “universal” way of representing what “and”-ness is really characterized by.
On the other hand, a rule like $A \implies C, B \implies C, A \vee B \vdash C$ strikes me as true upon reflection, but not a “thought pattern” we might consciously draw upon in thinking. So the question to me is trying to find equivalent sets of inference rules which may reflect the necessary “rules of reasoning” for each, or some, of the symbols, in a different way.
I’m trying to think how to do this. I imagine there should be a mathematical formalism first, which can guide implementation in code. Let’s stick to propositional logic for now, to keep this simple, and not include quantifiers. It seems like this could be an extension of the signature for Boolean algebras including a $\vdash$ symbol. So then maybe the theory would look something like:
$$\sigma = \{\wedge, \vee, \neg, \implies, \vdash\}$$
$$\forall X, Y [X \wedge Y \vdash X]$$
$$\forall X, Y [X, Y \vdash X \wedge Y]$$
$$\forall X, Y [X \vdash X \vee Y]$$
$$\forall X, Y, Z [X \implies Z, Y \implies Z, X \vee Y \vdash Z]$$
$$\ldots$$
And so on.
Now the goal is to consider if there is any generalized algorithm for enumerating the terms of a first-order theory or not.
I believe that if we have a system with rules like $R1$, $R2$, etc. (which can be thought of either as functions or as relations, I think), if they are totally defined on all the elements in the domain, the question of how to enumerate terms is just the question of how many permutations you can make of $n$ rules for $m$ applications - simple combinatorics.
If the rules are ‘conditional’ (are only defined for some terms), I haven’t yet thought about enumeration strategies for this case. Maybe it could get a lot more complicated by separating the domain into multiple sets, each one being closed with respect to one of the ‘rules’ (operations). Or, in the worst case, you just enumerate all terms freely but do a condition check to see if you should throw out any of these terms.
Once I understand how to enumerate the terms of what I think is essentially a “partial algebra”, I also want to figure out how to find alternative collections of formulae that are equivalent to natural deduction. I’m wondering if for all of the terms enumerated (above), you can form all subcollections, then enumerate each such theory, then finally find some way to check if two theories are equivalent?
